# How do I modify an item in a pandas dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to be able to access an excel spreadsheet and modify the values in it which say AHU 01-01 to AHU-01-01. I would like to take the "AHU " and change it to "AHU-" without losing the numbers which follow right after.

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel("MDCC AHU Schedule FOR PYTHON.xlsx")
ahunameonschedule = df1.iloc[0]
columns = pd.Index([ahunameonschedule])
```

Here is the output from the code above:

Index([[nan, 'DESIGNATION', nan, 'AHU 01-01', 'AHU 02-01', 'AHU 02-02', 'AHU 02-03', 'AHU 02-04', 'AHU 03-01', 'AHU 03-02', 'AHU 03-03', 'AHU 04-01', 'AHU 04-02', 'AHU 04-03', 'AHU 04-04', 'AHU 04-05', 'AHU 05-01', 'AHU 05-02', 'AHU 05-03', 'AHU 05-04', 'AHU 05-05', 'AHU 06-01', 'AHU 06-02', 'AHU 06-03', 'AHU 06-04', 'AHU 06-05', 'AHU 07-01', 'AHU 07-02', 'AHU 07-03', 'AHU 07-04', 'AHU 07-05', 'AHU 08-01', 'AHU 08-02', 'AHU 08-03', 'AHU 08-04', 'AHU 08-05', 'AHU 09-01', 'AHU 09-02', 'AHU 09-03', 'AHU 09-04', 'AHU 09-05', 'AHU 10-01', 'AHU 10-02', 'AHU 10-03', 'AHU 10-04', 'AHU 10-05']], dtype='object')

Here is what I've tried:

```
df1.rename(index={'AHU':'AHU-'}, level = 0, inplace=True)
df1
```

Additionally, how could I add conditionals to account for if a value doesn't have "AHU " within it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {'row_num': [1,2,3,4,5],
      'col_to_change': ['AHU 03-01', 'AHU 03-02', 'AHU 03-03', 'AHU 04-01', 'AHU 01-01']}



df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df['changed_column'] = df[['col_to_change']].apply(lambda x : "-".join(x[0].split())
                                               , axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas rename function plus regex to rename columns.  You could use regex's \A  to test for whether the column starts with AHU or not.  Here's one way to do it:

```
import regex as re

row1list = ['a', 100, '2020/03/01', 'abc']
row2list = ['b', 200, '2020/03/01', 'xyz']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list],
                  columns=['AHU 03-01', 'AHU 03-02', 'AHU 03-03', '04-02 AHU '])

df2 = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('AHU ', 'AHU_', x))

print(df2)
#   AHU_03-01  AHU_03-02   AHU_03-03 04-02 AHU_
# 0         a        100  2020/03/01        abc
# 1         b        200  2020/03/01        xyz
# note it renames the trailing 'AHU ' in the last column

df3 = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('\\AAHU ', 'AHU_', x))
print(df3)
#   AHU_03-01  AHU_03-02   AHU_03-03 04-02 AHU 
# 0         a        100  2020/03/01        abc
# 1         b        200  2020/03/01        xyz
# note it leaves the 'AHU ' in the last column alone
```